# Using velocity.js in angular component

Tags: angular, velocity.js

I am trying to create an angular component that implements [this codepen script](https://codepen.io/mn8809/pen/ByWQXJ).

I created the component using `ng g component <my-comp-name>` so I have the 3 HTML, CSS and ts files in my component.

The HTML and CSS section I just copy-pasted it. The JS part is always the difficulty in merging. Mostly because I have this velocity function.

I tried the following [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-velocity). I used `npm install angular-velocity --save` and added `<script src="node_modules/angular-velocity/angular-velocity.min.js"></script>` in the component HTML.

I tried to see if this worked changing the following line:

`<div ng-view class="velocity-opposites-transition-slideUpIn hover-notify">Hover Me!</div>` But no animation is shown in the Hover me! text.

What am I doing wrong? or is there an easier way to merge these codes?

---

**More things I tried:**

In the end, the jQuery part I succeeded using it by doing `import * as $ from "jquery";` I tried something similar but all variations fail: `import {Velocity} from 'velocity-animate';`

With this [link](http://www.independent-software.com/velocity-js-tutorial-accelerated-javascript-animation.html) I used:`import {Velocity} from 'velocity-animate';` and then replace line `$(".hex-wrap").velocity("callout.pulse");` with `Velocity(document.getElementsByClassName("hex-wrap"), "callout.pulse");` but nothing.

Please! I basically just want to be able to use `$(<sth>).velocity(...);`. I know I am a newbie but how hard can it be?

---

**I solved my problem with a hack (I am still looking for how to use velocity in angular)**
I did something that "solved" the issue.

I did `import 'src/app/languages/computer/script.js';` with the JS directly downloaded from the webpage and at the end of the HTML file I also added it as a script with `<script src="'src/app/languages/computer/script.js'"></script>`.

There was an issue in the css file. I changed:

```
.code-description * {
display: none;
}
```

for

```
div[class$="-desc"] {
  display: none;
}
```

So I technically have it working with JavaScript and not using my component ts.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add `node_modules/angular-velocity/angular-velocity.min.js` in the script section of your `angular.json`:

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/angular-velocity/angular-velocity.min.js"
]
```

**Edit**: actually this script is for AngularJS, it cannot work with Angular.

Comment: I'm not using AngularJS but it may be useful if someone reading this question is using it. So thanks.